# Understanding MVVM pattern elements

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I’m struggling to understand how to use MVVM pattern correct way. I read few articles and watched tutorials on youtube but still don’t grasp few things. I don’t want link to documentation because it didn’t help me to understand what I have problems with.

I understand that in MVVM is built from 3 layers. Correct me if I’m wrong.

•   Model – with properties and validation of their data. Example: product with information about name, price, weight etc. cs file with c#.

•   View – User interface, what is seen. In WPF that would be file containing XAML.

•   View model – Contains elements that are bind to the elements in View like button or DataGrid, can change datacontext. Cs file with c#, created automatically when I add new page to the project with this same name as XAML file with default method InitializeComponent();. Correct?

My questions:

•   Does that mean that the simplest MVVM project contains 3 files: 2 .cs and 1 XAML?

•   Where do I suppose to put methods that update data in database based on what I change in the View? In View model or Model?

•   View model should only have metod like “button click” that starts method from other cs file? Or also have methods to calculate data and connection to database?

•   Where do I suppose to put methods like “button click”? That is View Model or other 4th file?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/msgulfcommunity/understanding-the-basics-of-mvvm-design-pattern)

Comment: You should always remember, that MVVM only describes the UI part of your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your confusion, as many of the basic elements of MVVM aren't as simple as they are often promoted to be. For the sake of keeping it simple (or at least simpler), I will only focus on MVVM implemented in Windows Presentation Foundation (as that is what your tag suggests you want).

**View**

Is the most user faced layer. In the simplest form, it can be a single window. The window consists of an `.xaml` file, which is where you typically define the graphical properties of your application. It is paired with a `.cs` file as well though. The `.cs` part of the window (aka view) is not to be confused with the view model though. Often, in MVVM patterns, it contains only very little code, as the majority of the code resides in the view model.

**ViewModel**

The code which connects the view to the rest of the application (we will get to that). This could be a method which, when invoked, sends a request to the database and updates the UI with the response. The update part however, does not happen directly. The view is connected to the view model via bindings (a kind of events I guess). Bindings mean that the view model does not know, if a view even exists. It just sees someone, who invokes some methods or asks for some properties.

**Model**

I wish I could give you a clear answer, but countless articles and tutorials about MVVM haven't provided me with a good understanding of these. In the most basic tutorials, these are often used directly as database entities, but for an actual application this is rarely a good solution. Also they are sometimes described as where the business logic resides, but this conflicts with stuff like Domain Driven Design (DDD). But you are right in the sense that they model some object, like for instance a person.

**The rest**

This is the part that is often missing in the tutorials. The MVVM pattern doesn't describe everything needed for an application. It is primarily a User Interface pattern (with the models sometimes breaking that rule). You may also need to look into services, repositories, Object Relation Mappers (like Entity Framework) and so on. However, keep all this stuff in seperate assemblies, away from the user interface.

If you want to use Caliburn Micro (a framework for MVVM), I would recommend watching [Tim Corey's introduction video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laPFq3Fhs8k) (even if you don't, it might still be worth the watch).

And also, don't give up, if it doesn't all make sense right away. I have made a handful of WPF applciations by now, and I still struggle with a lot of the concepts (as you can see from my answer).

Keep trying. Keep failing. Keep learning!

Answer (score -1):

Try with [Caliburn Micro](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/) MVVM framework for initial understanding. Try to understand design patterns and breathe it. Then MVVM is a sugar candy.

Comment: Patjan, I don't think that suggesting a framework is appropriate here (though the answer is extremely broad). You'd want to describe what MVVM means and is used for.

Answer (score -1):

Do check [Pavel Anikhouski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4728685/pavel-anikhouski)'s comment.

Trying to answer your questions directly:

1. Does that mean that the simplest MVVM project contains 3 files: 2 .cs and 1 XAML?

> View = XAML + .cs VM = .cs Model = .cs So 4 files but the first two are coupled that is why it may look as only one

2. Where do I suppose to put methods that update data in database based on what I change in the View? In View model or Model?

> Changes to the Data are controlled by the Model. Validations you can set in the View, business rules you can set in the ViewModel.

3. View model should only have method like “button click” that starts method from other cs file? Or also have methods to calculate data and connection to database?
4. Where do I suppose to put methods like “button click”? That is View Model or other 4th file?

> Handling button click should be in View Model - click to redirect does not go to Model
>   Connection to database is on the Model - click to call data goes to Model

Hope it helps you out.